# Как подключить локальную базу данных в NetBeans 8.2

Tags: java, база-данных, netbeans

Я установил IDE NetBeans 8.2 и теперь стоит задача реализовать в приложении локальную базу. Сама база будет создаваться и наполняться отдельно от приложения. Мне только нужно её подключить и брать данные. Но я этого не могу сделать.

Пробовал множество способов.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC {
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
      Connection c = null;

      try {
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
   }
}
```

На что получаю ошибку

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`

Или, если уберу `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:test.db`

Я добавил библиотеку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я по прежнему получаю ошибки, которые указал выше. Я использую jdk1.8.0_201 более новую не могу, возникают проблемы с самой IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь в том, что библиотека jdbc-драйвера SQLite прописана в свойствах CLASSPATH проекта.

То есть открываете свойства проекта, раздел Libraries, и там эта библиотека с драйвером задана в закладке (Tab) Compile. Убедитесь, что эта библиотека указана в закладке Run.

[image: Свойства проекта]

Картинка взята из интернет, нетбинса под рукой нет, чтобы сделать более релевантный скриншот. Пусть не смущает пустота в закладке Compile в данном случае.

Проблема возникает оттого, что драйвер SQLLite виден при компиляции проекта, но при выполнении этого проекта путь к этому драйверу не передаётся в CLASSPATH выполняемого проекта.

И интерпретатор Java при выполнении вашего кода просто не может найти нужного класса.

Comment: Во вкладки run не было этой библиотеки, добавил, запустил, заработало. Спасибо